# c# order of operation confusion

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

[Operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWRIL.png)Guys my noob brain is having issues following this simple order of operation, would anybody be kind enough to enlight me on how is the computer handling this order of operation?.

Running this on Unity it throws the result printed on the book, but as simple as the operation maybe I cannot see how the computer is doing the operation.

Comment: show your code please

Comment: Just embed it on a picture, sorry for that!

Comment: its simple mathematics, just learn **BODMAS rule**

Comment: `5 + 4 - 3 / 2 * 1 = 9 - 3 / 2 * 1 = 9 - 1 * 1 = 9 - 1 = 8`

Comment: `5 + (4 - 3) / 2 * 1 = 5 + 1 / 2 * 1 = 5 + 0 * 1 = 5 + 0 = 5`

Comment: As almost everywhere else: multiplication/division overrules addition/subtraction => first the `/` and `*` are applied then the `-` .. Except you use explicit `( ) ` scopes in order to define a different precedence ... this is less a c# than rather a general math question

Comment: @derHugo - It's probably more a computer science question as it uses integer maths.

Comment: @Enigmativity yes and no .. it is basically the same rules also in normal math calculations ^^ integer maths in c# just basically follows the same precedence rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to first learn the mathematics BODMAS rule and how the precedence works. Refer to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations).

Now coming to your question.

it will become 5 + 1/2.

1/2 will become 0 because both the numerator and denominator are int.

and 5 + 0 is 5